How to store a python file with json?
For my programming class, I would like to write a code that can access scores from previous runs of this game. I found some information off of this site (specifically from @olinox14. Any JSON related pieces of code are from them). This is what I have so far:
import random
import json

i = True
while i == True:

    score_file = r"/pat/to/score/file.json"
    try:
        with open(score_file, 'r') as f:
            scores = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        scores = {}

    user_name = input("What's your username?")
    print("Let's play a guessing game! I'll think of a number between two numbers of your choice, and you'll have to guess it. I'll tell you when you're close!")
    min = int(input("What do you want the minimum to be?"))
    limit = int(input("What do you want the limit to be?"))

    random_number = random.randint(min, limit )
    user_number = int(input("Give me a number between " + str(min) + " and " + str(limit) + "."))
    score = 1

    while user_number != random_number:
        if random_number < user_number:
            print("Think lower! Let's try again.")
        if random_number > user_number:
            print("Think higher! Let's try again.")
        if user_number < min or user_number > limit:
            print("That's not between " + str(min) + " and " + str(limit) + "!")
        if user_number == random_number + 2 or user_number == random_number - 2:
            print("You're getting closer! Your guess is just two away.")
        if user_number == random_number + 1 or user_number == random_number - 1:
            print("You're very close; just one away!")
        user_number = int(input("Give me a number between 1 and " + str(limit) + "."))
        score = score + 1

    while user_number == random_number:
        scores[user_name] = score
        print("Congratulations! You guessed it!")

        print("You guessed it in " + str(score) + " tries.")
        if score == 1:
            print("You guessed it in 1 try. Good job!")
        break

    while True:
        go_again = input("Would you like to go again? Type yes or no.")
        if go_again == "yes":
            print("Good luck!")
            break
        elif go_again == "no":
            print("Goodbye!")
            i = False
            break
        else:
            print("You didn't type yes or no! Please try again.")
with open(score_file, 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(scores, f)
scores_sorted = sorted([(p, s) for p, s in scores.items()], reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
for player, score in scores_sorted:
    print(player, score)

I truly have no idea how this works or how I should go about fixing it. Whenever the program reaches the last part, I receive this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Grade\Python\number game.py", line 62, in <module>
    with open(score_file, 'w+') as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/pat/to/score/file.json'

I have zero idea what this means. Please explain how to fix this like you're talking to a five year old.

You copied and pasted r"/path/to/score/file.json" without realizing that it was just a placeholder. You need to provide the pathname of an actual file on your system, including the actual directories. For example, if you have a directory /Users/julia then you could use "/Users/julia/scores.json"

While your open(score_file, 'w+') will create a file in the specified directory if one is not there, it will not create the directory structure.

Before you write, ensure that the destination folder exists Path(pathlib.Path(score_file ).parent).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

At the start of the file
score_file = r"/pat/to/score/file.json"

This should be changed to the location on your computer where the file will be located. Either change this to the location where you want to store it, or simply change it to
score_file = r"file.json"

If you want to store the file in the folder where the python script is located

Thank you so much! I'd "upvote" your answer but this website hates me. :)

You're welcome, good luck with your programming class

"If you want to store the file in the folder where the python script is located"  that is relative to your working directory

Ah yes because that's definitely not going to make it overcomplicated for someone who is clearly new to programming
